# Explanation for the meaning of the lowest value of $f'(x)$ in this task

Tags: derivatives

I see that when $f'(x)=0$ we have the value of $x$ where the value of $y$ is the largest or smallest. But in this task, what is the meaning of the lowest value of $f'(x)$? I don't understand how we can take the $x$ value from the derivative and the $y$ value from the function and get this information, and especially in this question I don't even know what the information is supposed to mean.

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what the derivative (also called the _gradient_) means geometrically?

Comment: I understand that the derivative is the slope of the tangent in one point on f. And that if $f'(x)=0$ the slope is zero and then the tangent is horizontal, and therefor this must be a bottom or top point?

Comment: Yes, the tangent is horizontal when the gradient is zero, but note that _does not_ correspond with the largest or the smallest values of $y$ in general. However, with this intuition, can you see why the smallest $f'(x)$ value corresponds to when $x = 12.5$?

Comment: @BillWallis So the tangents biggest slope is in this point? That means the production after this point is reduced the most onward?

Comment: Yes, the tangents largest _negative_ slope is at this point, so at this point the _rate of production_ reaches it's lowest point. Note that the _rate of production_ does start to increase again after this point.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of a function $f$ describes the *gradient* of the function at that point. When $f'(x) = 0$, this corresponds to when the curve has zero gradient, or when the tangent line to $f$ at $x$ is horizontal. Note that this *does not* correspond with the largest or the smallest values of $y$ in general; for example, the function $f(x) = x^{3}$ has derivative $f'(x) = 3x^{2}$ so that $f$ has zero gradient at $x = 0$, but this has $y$-coordinate $y = 0$ so it is neither the largest nor the smallest value of $y$ on $f$ if $f$ is defined on the whole of the real line.

Note that a positive $f'(x)$ value corresponds to $f$ increasing in $y$ as $x$ increases, and a negative $f'(x)$ value corresponds to $f$ decreasing in $y$ as $x$ increases. Thus, when $f'(x)$ is a large *negative* number, this means that $f$ is *decreasing quickly*, so it will be going *down steeply* (as $x$ increases). Similarly, when $f'(x)$ has a large *positive* number, this means that $f$ is *increasing quickly*, so it will be going *up steeply* (as $x$ increases).

In terms of your example, a large positive $f'(x)$ value corresponds to a large *rate of change of production*, so rate of production is increasing as the days pass. A large negative $f'(x)$ value also corresponds to a large *rate of change of production* but in a negative way, so rate of production is decreasing as the days pass. If $f'(x)$ is zero, then the rate of production stays the same.